# Conditional content in html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, layout

i have a footer as the last element in my application.html.erb page, however for one page in the whole site, i do not want the footer to appear.

Whats the best way to handle this? every solution i come up with is wet (not dry)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why don't you create a specific layout for this single page? It should be more maintainable than any extra logic.

DRY is not a goal to reach, it's like a conditional warning and like all warnings, you can ignore them if it makes sense.

---

If you really insist, do this:

```
<% unless defined? @no_footer %>
  your html here
<% end %>
```

So the footer will ***disappear*** only if you set the instance variable in your controller:

```
@no_footer = true
```

Another way could be to check params action/controller and put the logic in a helper method.

Comment: Problem with that is it is identical to my application.html.erb minus the footer. Not very dry.

Comment: This really helped me out! Was considering parsing the current request url and all kinds of nasty stuff. This is definitely the best way to go!